# How to tie RelayCommand to IsChecked property?

Tags: wpf, relaycommand, ischecked

So far, I had to rely on code behind event to check or uncheck the buttons (e.g. Bold font toolbar button), and I wonder if there is a better and cleaner way to do it using RelayCommand because it is already binding to a RelayCommand for Execute and CanExecute.

Using RelayCommand, a button can easily be enabled or disable by providing CanExecute delegate. Is there a way to tie another delegate to button's (or menu's) IsChecked property?

Comment: Any reason to not use a boolean value on a backing Model, ie...`IsSelected`?

Comment: Why not bind `CheckBox.IsChecked` to `Button.IsEnabled`?

Comment: To Aaron Mclver: I need to use polling mechanism because there is a third party control involved and I don't get the event for that.

Comment: To Rachel: Once a button is disabled, you cannot click it again to enable it.